# Mixed derivative of a smooth function

Tags: inequality, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I am struggling with a problem I am providing below. Honestly, I don't know if it could be solved at all. Here it is.

Let $f\in L^2$ is a function of two variables (say $x$ and $y$) and $\hat f$ is its Fourier transformation. One could easily check that $|\widehat{f_{xy}}|\leq|\widehat{f_{xx}}|+|\widehat{f_{yy}}|$. Here $|\widehat{f_{xy}}|$, etc. are the mixed derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$.

And now my question is whether a similar inequality exists if $f$ is a smooth function (i.e. whether $\widehat{f_{xy}}$ could be evaluated by $\widehat{f_{xx}}$ and $\widehat{f_{yy}}$)?

If anyone has ever crashed into something at least similar, I would be thankful if s/he shares experience. :)

Thank you all!

Comment: The double Riesz transforms give exactly what you want: They express $\partial_{xy} f$ in terms of $\Delta f$ the Laplacian of $f$.

Comment: Sorry to ask a irreverent question , in which course one reads about these topics involving fourier transforms ? i read these from a book of course named signal processing , which i think has something to do with engineering , but i never encountered things such as sobolev spaces

Comment: Thank you Jose27 for the comment! I think this solves the issue. :) All the best. Fourier transform is usually a subject of a separate course. It could be also mentioned in a PDE course. This is based on my experience. Let others share their views. :)